# Using the MyWeather2 web service in android

Tags: android, web-services, android-studio

I am new to android , and I need an example to use / consume the following Web service in an application developed on android studio :

http://www.myweather2.com/developer/weather.ashx?uac=ENHRNh-psb&uref=53694bca-82a0-4de3-8a9b-70e4fe0b3e94

I would be very useful to be very specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JSON API instead of XML, that will make your task easier.

```
public class QueryBuilder {

//This is your unique key as I can see in the URL
private static final String KEY = "ENHRNh-psb";

// Take output as JSON instead of XML
private static final String OUTPUT = "json";

private static final String BASE_URL = "http://www.myweather2.com/developer/weather.ashx?";

private String query;

public QueryBuilder() {

    //build the base query with key and output
    this.query = BASE_URL + "uac=" + KEY + "&output=" + OUTPUT;
}

//Example of methods which you can add according to your requirement
public QueryBuilder setLocalityFilter(String locality) {
    this.query = this.query + "&filters={\"locality\":{\"$eq\":\"" + locality + "\"}}";
    return this;
}

public String build() {
    return this.query;
}
}
```

Example of JSON parser class

```
public class JsonParser {

public static ArrayList<Restaurant> parseHTTPResponse(String responseString) {
    ArrayList<Restaurant> restaurantArrayList= new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        JSONObject baseObject = new JSONObject(responseString);
        JSONObject responseObject = baseObject.getJSONObject("response");
        JSONArray restaurantArray = responseObject.getJSONArray("data");
        for (int i =0; i<restaurantArray.length();i++) {
            Restaurant restaurant = new Restaurant();
            JSONObject restaurantObject = restaurantArray.getJSONObject(i);
            restaurant.setName(restaurantObject.getString("name"));
            restaurant.setAddress(restaurantObject.getString("address"));
            restaurant.setRating(restaurantObject.getDouble("rating"));
            // Check if the restaurant has its cuisine listed, if yes add it to type
            if(restaurantObject.has("cuisine")) {
                JSONArray cuisineArray = restaurantObject.getJSONArray("cuisine");
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                for (int j = 0; j < cuisineArray.length(); j++) {
                    String cuisine = cuisineArray.getString(j);
                    stringBuilder.append(cuisine);
                    stringBuilder.append(" ,");
                }
                restaurant.setType(stringBuilder.toString());
            }
            restaurantArrayList.add(restaurant);
        }
    }
    catch (JSONException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return restaurantArrayList;
}
}
```

Build the query like this

```
String httpQuery = new QueryBuilder().setLocalityFilter(query).build();

try {
            HttpRequest request =  HttpRequest.get(httpQuery);
            if (request.ok()) {
                String response = request.body();
                restaurantArrayList = JsonParser.parseHTTPResponse(response);
            }
            return restaurantArrayList;
    } catch (HttpRequest.HttpRequestException exception) {
            return null;
}
```